# adda relative path connection string app.config

Tags: wpf, configuration

i want to add relative path instead of code below :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dataEntities" 
 connectionString="datasource=&qout;C:/Project/Sqlite.db'"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the path, so just the filename remains?

Comment: i want a code similar below: ~/Project/Sqlite.db

Comment: Ok so what happens if you make that the connection string?